# Timecode/TimeStamp in RTMP live streaming using Adobe Media Server and FMLE

Tags: video-streaming, adobe, jwplayer, flash-media-server, fmle

Am trying to stream a video on to Adobe media server(using RTMP) through FMLE and play it on my web site using JWPlayer. i could stream the video successfully, but know i want to get the timestamp/timecode on the stream. does Adobe media server and FMLE support this kind of use-case ? if not is there any other way to achieve the same. any comments/suggestion/pointers appreciated .

Thanks in Advance

Regards

Deepak

Comment: You might be able to use the JW Player's API to see how many seconds have streamed using onTime() - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference

Answer (score 0):

FMLE has it and I bet Adobe Media Server also has it. See Timecode ;)
[image]